# close div when clicked outside the div area

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code.I am trying to close the div,when clicked outside the Div,I have searched through this forum but can not find a solution -Here is a fiddle- [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/va68mw95/)

```
$('#hideshow1').on("click", function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $("#req").toggle();

});

$(window).on("click keydown", function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault() /*For the Esc Key*/
  if (e.keyCode === 27 || !$(e.target).is(function() {return $("#req, #hideshow1")})) {
    $("#req").hide()
  }
}).focus()
```

Comment: What do you mean by outside the div? Isit this div going to be wrapped around another div? or some sort of another HTML container?

Comment: i mean clicked any where in the page apart from inside the div `req`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Div `req` width is 100% of screen. The `frame` width is the same as the border.

```js
$('#hideshow1').on("click", function() {
  if ($("#frame").is(":visible") == false) {
    $("#frame").show();
  }
  $('#hideshow1').text("Click outside div to hide it.");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $("#frame"); //Used frame id because div(req) width is not the same as the frame 
  if ($("#frame").is(":visible")) {
    if (!container.is(e.target) //check if the target of the click isn't the container...
      && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      container.hide();
      $('#hideshow1').text("Click to see div");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickme">
  <a class="req_pic_link" id="hideshow1">Click outside div to hide it.</a>
</div>
<div id="req">
  <iframe id="frame" src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @jake123 check out my solution. it work interfere with the rest of your code and events conflicts ....

Comment: thanks alot it worked just fine just what i needed just did a bit of editing and it worked :D :D :D Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please check this out.

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $("#req").hide();
  // add some code
});

$('#clickme').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // add some code
});
```

Test code here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abrztuxx/)

Answer (score 2):

The function argument for `.is()` is used to test every element in the set, and needs to return a boolean value as to whether the element matches or not - it should not return a jQuery collection.

However for what you are trying to do you should only pass a selector instead of a function to `.is()` like this:

```
if (e.keyCode === 27 || !$(e.target).is("#req, #hideshow1")) {
    $("#req").hide()
}
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va68mw95/4/).
(Note that it won't work if you click to the right of the div, but that is because you are still clicking on `#req` because it doesn't have a specified width.)

Comment: the fiddle works fine but when i implement the same thing in ma webpage it doesn't work

Comment: is it because i have another toggle option in the same page ?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really say. If it works in the fiddle but not in your code, there are a number of things that could be going wrong, including other events conflicting or stopping what this is meant to do.

Comment: isnt there another way to do this ?

Comment: There's almost always more than one way to do something with JavaScript. I've just offered you one way.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide another solution if you can

Answer (score 0):

You need to add click event to the document and check that clicked target and any of it parent don't have required class:

```js
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  var divClass = 'my-class';
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass(divClass) && !$(e.target).parents().hasClass(divClass)) {
    // do something...
  }
});
```